# Memory leak with images in Firefox 28.0

Tags: image, firefox, memory-leaks

Wrote a simple test case to do repetitive adding/removing of 100 images from the DOM:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/></head>

<body>
    <div id="the-place"></div>

    <script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var Person = function (firstName, lastName, loginId)
        {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.loginId = loginId;
            this.fullName = this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
        };

        var firstNames = [
            "George",
            "Sandra",
            "Billy",
            "David",
            "Jason"
        ];
        var lastNames = [
            "Clark",
            "Smith",
            "Doe",
            "Randall",
            "Crank"
        ];
        var loginIds = ["gclark", "ssmith", "bdoe", "drandall", "jcrank"];

        var unPopulateAndRepopulateDom = function ()
        {               
            var thePlaceNode = document.getElementById("the-place");
            while (thePlaceNode.firstChild) {
                thePlaceNode.removeChild(thePlaceNode.firstChild);
            }               
            for (var i=0; i<100; i++)
            {
                var person = new Person (
                    firstNames[Math.floor (Math.random ()*firstNames.length)],
                    lastNames[Math.floor (Math.random ()*lastNames.length)],
                    loginIds[Math.floor (Math.random ()*loginIds.length)]
                );

               thePlaceNode.insertAdjacentHTML ( 'beforeend', 
                    '<div>' +
                    'First Name: <span id="first-name-' + i + '">' +    
person.firstName     + '</span><br>' +
                    'Last Name: <span id="last-name-' + i + '">' + person.lastName + 

'</span><br>' +
                    '<img src="acc_icons.png"/>' +
                    'Full Name: <span id="full-name-' + i + '">' + person.fullName + 

'</span><br><br>' +
                    '</div>'
                );
                person = null;
            }
        }

        var count = 0;
        var startItUp = function ()
        {
            count++;
            unPopulateAndRepopulateDom ();

            if (count > 1000)
            {
                setTimeout (startItUp, 10000); // Finally take a breather for 10 

 seconds
                count = 0;
            }
            else
                setTimeout (startItUp, 1);
        }

        startItUp ();
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Monitoring the firefox.exe process in Windows Task Manager, it appears that Firefox is leaking memory at approximately 1 MB per iteration. After 1000 iterations of adding/removing images from the DOM, we implemented a 10 second pause to allow the garbage collectors to "catch up". Of course, we shouldn't have to pause but we wanted to see if this made a difference and it didn't (for FireFox). This exact test case runs perfectly in IE 10 and Chrome (no memory leak after 8 hours of execution). Note: My development box is quad-core, 16.0 GB of RAM, Windows 7/64-bit.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

A JSFiddle can be found here (http://jsfiddle.net/37wZ7/7/).